# How Nava-Durga correspond to NavaGraha?

Tags: durga, navagraha, nava-durga

I have read somewhere that each NavaGraha is presided by a Durga. I want to know which Devi presides over which planet.

Comment: 'BG 7.4: Earth, water, fire, air, space, mind, intellect, and ego—these are eight components of my material energy.' Ashtsiddhi or complete control of 8 divisions of Prakriti is of 9th Purusha/conciousness. Nav Durga is henotheist Shakta counterpart of given 9 divisions as Purusha consciousness is Prakriti herself.